# From ArrayFire to OpenGL on AMD?

Tags: opengl, opencl, amd-gpu, arrayfire

Is it possible to go from ArrayFire to OpenGL and back using an AMD graphics card?

There is an [article](http://arrayfire.com/remote-off-screen-rendering-with-opengl/) on how to do it using CUDA. Any hints on using a similar method for OpenCL, so it can be used cross-platform?

### Update

What I would like to do in the end is take an `af::array`, convert it to an OpenGL texture and render it with my custom shader to the screen or to another texture (assuming a given OpenGL context, for example from Qt).

Comment: We have a library called forge that does this automatically. If you want specific helper functions, please create a new issue on github.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili: Thanks for the comment. But this is only for displaying, no? See my update of the question...

Comment: What you need is a way to tweak the Arrayfire context creation flags to include a gl share flag. After that you can get the underlying cl_buffer of any array, and pass it to your gl context and back.

Comment: @JanRüegg Please make this a github issue so we can have a better discussion on this. SO is not the avenue for this discussion.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili Ok, I'll do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible so far. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/1029) on the official bugtracker, though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the OpenGL-OpenCL interop via cl_khr_gl_sharing is not supported by the newest ArrayFire (at least for Intel graphic cards (Iris and so on)). 
For me it looks like the cl_khr_gl_sharing is generally not supported by ArrayFire.

Comment: @ Pavan Yalamanchili Well, I referred to: "OpenGL-OpenCL interop via cl_khr_gl_sharing is not supported " here: [link](http://arrayfire.com/opencl-on-intel-hd-iris-graphics-on-linux/).